# Get the first regular link that is not located between brackets out of a paragraph using python (bs4)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I need to write a program in python using bs4 that shows me the path of one wikipedia site to another, for this I have to take the first link on the current wikipedia site that is located in the 'div', id=bodycontent in the first paragraph.

Though, there is a restriction that I have to take the first link that is not located between brackets fe:

*Epistemology (/ɪˌpɪstəˈmɒlədʒi/ (listen); from Ancient Greek ἐπιστήμη (epistḗmē) 'knowledge', and -logy) is the branch of philosophy concerned with knowledge. Epistemologists study the nature, origin, and scope of knowledge, epistemic justification, the rationality of belief, and various related issues. Epistemology is considered a major subfield of philosophy, along with other major subfields such as ethics, logic, and metaphysics.[1]*

In this paragraph, Ancient Greek is a link but I cant use that one because it's between brackets so the link that I have to use is *branch of philosophy* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epistemology).

My problem is that I don't know how I can find the first link that is not between brackets in the first paragraph. This is what I already have:

````
while current != end:

        session.get(url)
        response = session.get(url)
        d = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
        body = d.find('div',id = "bodyContent")
        d = body.find("p")
        while d.find('a') == None:
            d = d.findNext("p")

        d = d.find("a")```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution could be get the first paragraph as text, replace `(` and `)` with custom tags and parse it again. For example:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epistemology"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

txt = (
    str(soup.select_one(".mw-parser-output p:has(a)"))
    .replace("(", "<bracket>")
    .replace(")", "</bracket>")
)

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, "html.parser")

a = soup.find(lambda tag: tag.name == "a" and not tag.find_parent("bracket"))
print(a)
```

Prints:

```html
<a href="/wiki/Outline_of_philosophy" title="Outline of philosophy">branch of philosophy</a>
```

Comment: thanks, much love. i passed my exam thanks to you